# Using while loop as input validation

Tags: java

I'm trying to use while loop to ask the user to reenter if the input is not an integer

for eg. input being any float or string

```
      int input;

      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

      System.out.print ("Enter the number of miles: ");
      input = scan.nextInt();
      while (input == int)  // This is where the problem is
          {
          System.out.print("Invalid input. Please reenter: ");
          input = scan.nextInt();
          }
```

I can't think of a way to do this. I've just been introduced to java

Comment: Take a look at the `Scanner.hasNext` methods. There you can determine which type the next input is.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `scan.nextInt()` will actually throw an `InputMismatchException` if the input cannot be parsed as an `int`.

Consider this as an alternative:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of miles: ");

    int input;
    while (true) {
        try {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.print("Invalid input. Please reenter: ");
            scan.nextLine();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("you entered: " + input);
```

Answer (score 1):

The javadocs say that the method throws a InputMismatchException if the input doesn;t match the Integer regex.  Perhaps this is what you need?

So...

```
int input = -1;
while(input < 0) {
  try {
     input = scan.nextInt();
  } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.print("Invalid input. Please reenter: ");
  }
}
```

as an example.

Comment: Except -1 is probably a valid number as far as you're concerned. The answer below mine would work.

Comment: FYI: "below" quickly loses its meaning based on edits and a users setting as seen in the tab (i.e., oldest, ...).